# What exactly is executable code?

Tags: linux

I know about executable code, but I don't know what it exactly is.(for the system)
(I'm thinking about .sh or something else)

I tried to find something out with www.google.com but there was no result.
Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: It's an oxymoron. "Code" presumes "execute-ability". Not-code cannot be executed. Is an ARM binary on my Mac 'executable code'?

Comment: Yes it is. It just isn't executable *by* your Mac.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax: precisely. But the same goes for "code not *presently* executed"! In John von Neumann's computer model, everything is data. While some of this data *may* be 'executable' (on your current CPU), it is not guaranteed that it will ever be.

Comment: True, but as @Jonathan.Brink points out, "precisely" is not a word normally associated with the definition of "executable code."

Comment: @Jongware sorry about nitpicking, but that's more like a tautology, not an oxymoron.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a loose term but I would interpret this as a program that can be executed.

For example, if we have a Java file it is not directly executable...it's just a bunch text to the end user. You can't run the file directly like:

```
./foo.java # bad
```

Conversely, if you had a sh script that could be **interpreted** by your shell (and it has the proper permissions set, such as the executable bit) then it *is* executable. For example you could do:

```
./foo.sh # good
```

Another example would be code that has been **compiled**. If that foo.java file had been compiled into byte code then (assuming it had a main function) it *could* be executed directly (not the .java file, but the output of the build).

```
java foo # good
```

So, I think in this context, executable code means a file with code in it that can be executed directly by an end user.

Comment: I once *nearly* broke my Windows installation - through the registry, I managed to remove `.exe` files from the list of "valid executable extensions". That made all of my programs 'data' - according to the OS, at least. It took some lateral thinking to repair that (`regedit.exe` did not work either).

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply, "executable code" is any sequence of program instructions which is intended to be executed in some environment without prior translation. For example, a "binary executable" contains instructions which can be carried out by an appropriate microprocessor. An "executable shell script" contains instructions which are meant to be executed as-is by a shell program; from the shell's perspective, the script contains executable code, but from the processor's perspective it doesn't.